# Division by subtraction - dividing the remainder by subtraction?

Tags: arithmetic

We can divide a number by subtraction and stop at the remainder as shown here - [How to divide using addition or subtraction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186421/how-to-divide-using-addition-or-subtraction).

But how do we continue to divide the remainder by subtraction ? I looked on google and could not find such answers. They don't go beyond the remainder.

For example, lets say we have $7/3$.
$7-3 = 4$
$4-3 = 1$
So, we have $2$ & $(1/3)$. How do we do the $1/3$ 
division using only subtraction ?

Comment: Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to divide beyond that point, that is, to divide the remainder, then presumably you want the full decimal expression of a non-integer.  In order to find the decimal expansion for $1/3$ via subtraction, we would have to say the following:
$$
1/3 = \frac1{10}\times (10/3)
$$
That is, find $10/3$, and shift the answer over by a decimal place.  So, we have
$$
1/3 = \frac1{10}\times 10/3\\
10-3-3-3 = 10-3\times 3 = 1\implies\\
1/3 = \frac1{10}\times(3R1) = \frac1{10}\left(3+\frac13\right)
$$
To say this another way, we know that if you take the decimal expansion for $\frac13$ and multiply it by $10$ (or shift the decimal place to the right), you get $3$ more than the decimal expansion for $\frac13$.  What does this recursive definition tell you about that decimal expansion?

By a similar process, we can find any terminating or repeating decimal. In other words, we have long division.

Comment: Please note that I dont want to use multiplication or division operators to do this.

Comment: If you want to get a decimal representation of a non-integer, you have to acknowledge that numbers after the decimal point are divided by $10$. What I have done is as close as you can get to division-free division, since the only division carried out is division by $10$, corresponding to a shift of the decimal point. The only multiplication I've done here is integer multiplication, which can alternately be done by repeated subtraction as shown.